# multirow table alignments, centering in combination with self defined columntypes

Tags: align, overleaf, multicolumn, multirow, cline

I've read a lot of table related posts, but couldn't find a specific solution for my problem. I know there was a bug with the multirow vertical centering of the last column, but it didn't work for me so I fixed it by manually adjusting it with \vspace{-0.3em}. But that can't be the solution. My Problem is that I like working with the self set column Type (in this case "P" that centers vertically in the cell. It works perfectly for the second column, but not the third. It just isn't an elegant solution for what I want. It looks like the following, but after hours of shifting the text in the cells manually by 0.1em steps.
[image: example in my compiler]

.

Additionally the vertical line at the bottom right corner "add-on cell" is not aligned with the vertical table line.
[image: not aligned]

Here is the minimal code I am using in Overleaf-LuaLatex compiler. I hope it is understandable like that. I have read how to ask a question, but I am quite new as a author here, so please forgive me for mistakes and thank you in advance. I am also very open for tips in syntax, if there is a problem.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage{amsmath}%mathem. Symbole
\usepackage{bm}%bold Math Symbols
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}%Zellenhöhe
\usepackage{booktabs}%Liniendicke



\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%horizontal centering


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Verortung der Stunde zum Thema Saccharose im Unterricht}
        \vspace{1.5ex}
        \centering
        \label{table5}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ %insgesamt: 0.864\textwidth
        \begin{tabular}{ | P{0.288\textwidth} | P{0.288\textwidth} | P{0.288\textwidth} |}
        \hline
        \small\textbf{\textit{Lernbereich}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{Unterrichtseinheiten}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{angesetzte Stunden}} 
        \\
        \hline
   \multirow{4}{*}[-5em]{\parbox{0.288\textwidth}{\centering C9-2: Atombau und gekürztes Periodensystem – Vom Kern-Hülle-Modell zum Energiestufenmodell und zum Ordnungsprinzip des gekürzten Periodensystems}}  &  Energiestufenmodell: Ionisierungsenergie, Elektronenkonfiguration & \vspace{-0.3em} 1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   & \textbf{Profil: Flammenfärbung und Linienspektrum} & \vspace{-1em} 3\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   &  gekürztes Periodensystem: Protonenzahl, Nukleonenzahl, Isotope; Hauptgruppen, Valenzelektronen; Perioden & \vspace{1em} 1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
    & Edelgaskonfiguration, Ionenladungszahl von Kationen und Anionen, Edelgasregel & \vspace{0.3em} 1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
    \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$\sum$ 9\,h}\\
    \cline{3-3}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have much time now, I quickly saw the last line. If someone in the meantime has been unable to help you further, I will come back to you. The last line \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & $\sum$ 9\,h\\.
you can watch too the packahe tabularray

Comment: That already is a nicely working fix for the second problem. Thank you very much. Didn't think of that approach, but seems very logic now in retroperspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

- `\resizebox` is bad. It makes your fonts inconsistent. Better is to calculate the column width so that it just fits. Subtract `4\arrayrulewidth` and `6\tabcolsep` from `\textwidth` and divide by 3.
- For vertical centering use `m{...}` instead of `p{...}`. Then you can get rid of the `\vspace`s.
- Don't put a `\parbox` in the `\multirow`. Instead use `=` instead of `*` as the second parameter.
- For the vertical bar: it should be at the end of the previous column, not the beginning of the next column.
- There is a `\cline{2-3}` too much (before `\hline`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage{amsmath}%mathem. Symbole
\usepackage{bm}%bold Math Symbols
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}%Zellenhöhe
\usepackage{booktabs}%Liniendicke



\newlength\Pcolwidth
\setlength\Pcolwidth{\dimexpr (\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}%horizontal and vertical centering

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Verortung der Stunde zum Thema Saccharose im Unterricht}
        \vspace{1.5ex}
        \centering
        \label{table5}
        \begin{tabular}{ | P{\Pcolwidth} | P{\Pcolwidth} | P{\Pcolwidth} |}
        \hline
        \small\textbf{\textit{Lernbereich}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{Unterrichtseinheiten}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{angesetzte Stunden}} 
        \\
        \hline
   \multirow{4}{=}[-5em]{\centering C9-2: Atombau und gekürztes Periodensystem – Vom Kern-Hülle-Modell zum Energiestufenmodell und zum Ordnungsprinzip des gekürzten Periodensystems}  &  Energiestufenmodell: Ionisierungsenergie, Elektronenkonfiguration &  1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   & \textbf{Profil: Flammenfärbung und Linienspektrum} &  3\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   &  gekürztes Periodensystem: Protonenzahl, Nukleonenzahl, Isotope; Hauptgruppen, Valenzelektronen; Perioden &  1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
    & Edelgaskonfiguration, Ionenladungszahl von Kationen und Anionen, Edelgasregel &  1-2\,h \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& $\sum$ 9\,h \\
    \cline{3-3}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second solution:**

Use `tabularx` and it will automatically calculate the column width. You need to redefine `\tabularxcolumn` to make it use `m{...}` columns.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage{amsmath}%mathem. Symbole
\usepackage{bm}%bold Math Symbols
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}%Zellenhöhe
\usepackage{booktabs}%Liniendicke
\usepackage{tabularx}


\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%horizontal centering


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}% vertical centering
        \caption{Verortung der Stunde zum Thema Saccharose im Unterricht}
        \vspace{1.5ex}
        \centering
        \label{table5}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | P | P | P |}
        \hline
        \small\textbf{\textit{Lernbereich}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{Unterrichtseinheiten}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{angesetzte Stunden}} 
        \\
        \hline
   \multirow{4}{=}[-5em]{\centering C9-2: Atombau und gekürztes Periodensystem – Vom Kern-Hülle-Modell zum Energiestufenmodell und zum Ordnungsprinzip des gekürzten Periodensystems}  &  Energiestufenmodell: Ionisierungsenergie, Elektronenkonfiguration &  1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   & \textbf{Profil: Flammenfärbung und Linienspektrum} &  3\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   &  gekürztes Periodensystem: Protonenzahl, Nukleonenzahl, Isotope; Hauptgruppen, Valenzelektronen; Perioden &  1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
    & Edelgaskonfiguration, Ionenladungszahl von Kationen und Anionen, Edelgasregel &  1-2\,h \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& $\sum$ 9\,h \\
    \cline{3-3}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

**Third solution:**

Use the 'tblr`environment from the`tabularray`package. For`\multirow`s which span taller than one-line rows this is often a better solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage{amsmath}%mathem. Symbole
\usepackage{bm}%bold Math Symbols
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}%Zellenhöhe
\usepackage{booktabs}%Liniendicke
\usepackage{tabularray}


\NewColumnType{P}{X[c,m]}%horizontal and vertical centering


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Verortung der Stunde zum Thema Saccharose im Unterricht}
        \vspace{1.5ex}
        \centering
        \label{table5}
        \begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth, colspec={| P | P | P |},vline{1,2} = {Z}{0pt}}
        \hline
        \small\textbf{\textit{Lernbereich}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{Unterrichtseinheiten}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{angesetzte Stunden}} 
        \\
        \hline
   \SetCell[r=4]{c,m} C9-2: Atombau und gekürztes Periodensystem – Vom Kern-Hülle-Modell zum Energiestufenmodell und zum Ordnungsprinzip des gekürzten Periodensystems  &  Energiestufenmodell: Ionisierungsenergie, Elektronenkonfiguration &  1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   & \textbf{Profil: Flammenfärbung und Linienspektrum} &  3\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
   &  gekürztes Periodensystem: Protonenzahl, Nukleonenzahl, Isotope; Hauptgruppen, Valenzelektronen; Perioden &  1-2\,h \\
   \cline{2-3}
    & Edelgaskonfiguration, Ionenladungszahl von Kationen und Anionen, Edelgasregel &  1-2\,h \\
    \hline
   &  & $\sum$ 9\,h \\
    \cline{3-3}
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. I highly appreciate the core answer and every tip around it.

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm, thanks to the suggestion made by @pascal974/@Pieter van Oostrum and the tabularray package.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularray}


\usepackage{amsmath}%mathem. Symbole
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

     \begin{table}
        \caption{Verortung der Stunde zum Thema Saccharose im Unterricht}
        \vspace{1ex}
        \centering
        \label{table8}
        \setlength\threecolwidth{\dimexpr (\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep)/3}

        \SetTblrInner{rowsep=5pt}
        \begin{tblr}{
        vline{1}={1-5}{solid},%erste vert. Linie in den Reihen {}
        colspec={Q[l,m,\threecolwidth]|Q[l,m,\threecolwidth]|Q[c,m,\threecolwidth]|}}% m vertical, c horiz. align
        \hline
        \small\textbf{\textit{Lernbereich}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{Unterrichtseinheiten}} & 
        \small\textbf{\textit{angesetzte Stunden}} 
        \\
        \hline
   \SetCell[r=4]{m} C9-2: Atombau und gekürztes Periodensystem – Vom Kern-Hülle-Modell zum Energiestufenmodell und zum Ordnungsprinzip des gekürzten Periodensystems
                        %
                        %
            &  Energiestufenmodell: Ionisierungsenergie, Elektronenkonfiguration & 1-2\,h \\
   \hline
            & \textbf{Profil: Flammenfärbung und Linienspektrum} &  3\,h \\
   \hline
            &  gekürztes Periodensystem: Protonenzahl, Nukleonenzahl, Isotope; Hauptgruppen, Valenzelektronen; Perioden &  1-2\,h \\
   \hline
            & Edelgaskonfiguration, Ionenladungszahl von Kationen und Anionen, Edelgasregel & 1-2\,h \\
    \hline
      \SetCell[c=2]{c}& & $\sum$ 9\,h\\
    \cline{3-3}
    \end{tblr}
    
    \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code from above; looks quite the same with better code]
It is very easy and I can center cells vertically with m and horizontally with c. (Q[m,c])

That is very neat. My only Problem being is that I am putting the whole tblr/tabular environment in a resizebox. I saw this once and do it from that moment on to prevent any table ever leaving my margins. I'd rather have it scaled down than going over the margins. But on the other hand I don't want different font sizes, so to determine the correct columnwidth, I let latex read the textwidth in cm or pt and divide that by the number of columns I have. That's the reason why in my code above it says for the cell type: Q[l,m,139.21471pt]. Quite an odd number and 0.3\textwidth doesn't work in that package and by experience a 3 column table has three 0.28\textwidth columns instead of "thirds" equalling 0.33\textwidth. Is there a more beautiful option to make three equally wide columns and prevent the whole thing from scaling down or leaving my margins?

Thanks again for the good help so far

edit: updated the code with the three column width

Comment: Update: The answer from @Pieter van Oostrum just solved this current problem as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

- I would a bit redesign a table: make last column narrower.
- One more proposition how to use `tabularray` package with some effort to make code short (as much is possible).
- For values I would use `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Verortung der Stunde zum Thema Saccharose im Unterricht}
\label{table5}
    \centering
\sisetup{range-phrase={\,--\,}}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-Y} = solid, hline{Z} = {Z}{solid},
             vline{1,2} = {1-Y}{solid}, vline{3,4} = {1-Z}{solid},
             colspec= {X[2,c]X[2,c,m]X[1,c, m]},
             colsep = 3pt,
             row{1} = {font=\small\itshape\bfseries, c}
             }
Lernbereich
    &   Unterrichtseinheiten
        &   angesetzte Stunden      \\
\SetCell[r=4]{m}  C9-2: Atombau und gekürztes Periodensystem –
                    Vom Kern-Hülle-Modell zum Energiestufenmodell
                    und zum Ordnungsprinzip des gekürzten Periodensystems
    &  Energiestufenmodell: Ionisierungsenergie, Elektronenkonfiguration 
        &  \qtyrange{1}{2}{\hour}    \\
   & \textbf{Profil: Flammenfärbung und Linienspektrum} 
        &  \qtyrange{1}{3}{\hour}    \\
   &    gekürztes Periodensystem: Protonenzahl, Nukleonenzahl, Isotope; Hauptgruppen, Valenzelektronen; Perioden 
        &  \qtyrange{1}{2}{\hour}    \\
    &   Edelgaskonfiguration, Ionenladungszahl von Kationen und Anionen, Edelgasregel 
        &  \qtyrange{1}{2}{\hour}    \\
   &    & $\sum= \qty{9}{\hour}$    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is a nice approach and makes my current code shorter and is a nice alternative to determine the right column size. I also changed to ragged left and had the tabular side to side to the tabularray version and the tabular looked nicer, because it did more pleasant looking linebreaks. Maybe it is just perception.